# Probability question in Venn diagram

Tags: probability

Look at [this PDF file's](http://www.sofworld.org/sites/default/files/CLASS%209.pdf) question No. 7( Under National Cyber Olympiad's subheading Logical Reasoning, it's in page 2)

As the question can't be understood without the diagram, I don't think it is worth effort to add the question text, as it would seem incomplete.

So, the answer is said to be 5400. That's (17/50)*10000.   Okay, but why? The question says the least number of people who read two newspapers. The people who read two news papers(different) are 8, 12, 5. And ones who read all three are only 2.
I guessed that 2 is deducted from 8, 12, 5 and the results are then added. But why is 2 subtracted from them? The two who read three also read at least two newspapers, don't they? So shouldn't it be added just once to sum of 8, 12, 5?

Please explain, 9th grader here, if it matters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of people who read *at least* two newspapers is $8+12+5+2=27$.  Then $\frac {27}{50}\cdot 10000=5400$